# `require': cannot load such file -- blockchain-wallet (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Working on Blockchain-wallet api whose initial step is to gem install blockchain-wallet, along with it should create wallet object hence used test.rb file to add queries as in documentation    https://github.com/Tolsi/blockchain-wallet-ruby. Used ruby test.rb command to run the file, got `require': cannot load such file -- blockchain-wallet (LoadError) load error. Checked with  gemset and ruby version, everything seems to look fine. What mistake leads to such an error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try to use:

```
require 'blockchain/wallet'
```

Comment: Added wallet.addresses to the file, got this error /home/min/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@blockchain/gems/blockchain-wallet-0.0.5/lib/‌​blockchain/wallet.rb:86:in `rescue in execute_request': uninitialized constant Blockchain::Wallet::OpenSSL (Blockchain::Wallet::BlockchainException) and idea how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

accepted

As the operator of the site I will try and answer the first question.

Server Side

The site currently runs on 4 dedicated servers, hosted in a locked cabinet. All servers run behind a dedicated cisco security appliance with intrusion detection. On the servers themselves various "booby traps" are set to alert the webmaster if an intrusion is detected.

The java code deployed to the Site is deployed in a single war (zip) file. Each server monitors the checksum of this file to detect any unauthorised changes to the code. In order to make reverse engineering our encryption schemes more difficult the the java class files are obfuscated using proguard.

A copy of every wallet is stored all our servers. Additionally the latest 50 versions of a wallet are stored on Amazon S3 and can be restored from the [Import / Export] section.

The server side code that handles wallets is open source.

The site is not vulnerable to CSRF requests as no login details or sensitive data is ever saved in session cookies.

In the time the Site has been running there has been handful of XSS vulnerabilities reported. None of these were on a wallet page and could not have resulted in any direct loss of funds.